# order only number in dataframe rows by rows import from csv

Tags: python, pandas, rows, tablesorter, python-3.9

I want to get ascending order all number of dataframe imported from a CSV file row-by-row:

I tried:

```
df_tirage = pd.read_csv('lotodata.csv', sep = ',', usecols=['day','month_year','num0','num1','num2','num3','num4','chance'])
for eachline in df_tirage:
    line = map(str, eachline.split(","))
    sorted_line = sorted(line)
```

[image: df-tirage]

Comment: Does the image show your expected output? Or does it show your original data?

Comment: `np.sort(df.filter(regex='num').values, axis=1)` or `np.sort(df.filter(regex='num').values)`?

Comment: @ansev a little FYI: `.values` is deprecated in favor of `.to_numpy()`

Comment: image show the original file , the output got the same header with index 0.1.2 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding it correctly, something might the following should do the trick.

```
df_tirage = pd.read_csv('lotodata.csv', sep = ',', usecols=['day','month_year','num0','num1','num2','num3','num4','chance'])

def sorter(num_arr):
    return np.sort(num_arr)

df_tirage[['num0', 'num1', 'num2', 'num3', 'num4']] = df_tirage.apply(lambda row : sorter(row[2:-1]), axis=1, result_type='expand')
```

We're essentially applying a sorting function row by row using lambda and then unpacking the sorted values into dataframe columns as we go.

Comment: thx for answer ,work fine

Comment: @freelandream Please consider accepting the answer if it solves your issue.

Comment: i dont know how ,i accept the answer

Comment: @freelandream just click on the gray tick sign on the left side of my answer.